# XSLT: number format

Tags: xslt

In XSL is function like CONTAIN, that if i have number with simbol like "123112'+:" then doesn't take it.

to be more precise:

```
<Number>111111</Number>
<Number>123123+</Number>
<Number>222222</Number>
<Number>222222+</Number>
```

answer:

```
111111
222222
```

I'm stuck with xslt 1.0 version

Comment: @Petras: Your question is not clear. Do you want to select those `Number` elements not having a value like this pattern "######+"?

Comment: Hem. not(contains(Number, '+')). Or pattern is more specific?

Comment: if we haven't only number element than don't take it. If 2020,we will take it, but if 2020+, we don't.

Comment: @Petras, sorry, but I'm lost in translation. Could you please rephrase "if we haven't only number element than don't take it"?

Comment: @Alejandro. sorry for that. I mean if we have only numbers then we show it. If we have number with symbols like +,?(for example:21231+) then we don't show it

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for yet another correct and easy solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach, exploiting number to boolean conversion.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Number[boolean(number()) or . = 0]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Number">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With input:

```
<Numbers>
    <Number>111111</Number>
    <Number>123123+</Number>
    <Number>222222</Number>
    <Number>222222+</Number>
</Numbers>
```

Correct result:

```
111111
222222
```

Quoting the spec:

> The boolean function converts its
>   argument to a boolean as follows:  a
>   number is true if and only if it is
>   neither positive or negative zero nor
>   NaN

Comment: @Dimitre, as I mentioned. "if zeros are unsignifican"

Comment: @Flack: A zero may be insignificant if it is in a left-starting group of zeroes that precede other digits before the decimal point or if the zero is in a right-ending groups of zeroes that are after the decimal point. Therefore, the number 0 is not an insignificant zero.

Comment: @Dimitre, yeah, it's a weak wording. What I meant "if elems with value 0" aren't significant.

Comment: @Flack: then you could fix the expression: `boolean(number()) or . = 0`

Comment: @Dimitre. Yeah, I just thought it would be obvious. Fixed now.

Comment: @Fack: this program doesn't work if we have " " and ".". I mean <Number>22222.</Number><Number>121 </Number> Result is wrong 22222. and 121

Comment: "22222." is, in fact, a valid floating-point number. E.g. floor(222222.) will give you 222222.

Comment: @Petras: If you want integers only you could use `.=floor()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following XPath to select all the nodes that contains numbers.  It will skip the ones with a plus sign in them.

```
Number[number(.)=number(.)]
```

Should work with XSLT 1.0

Comment: +1 Correct semantic (instance of number data type). Do note that `Number[.=number()]` it's enough for XPath 1.0 . In Xpath 2.0 we would use `instance of` operator.

Comment: can i use this method with value-of select:<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Number[number(.)=number(.)])"/>

Comment: @Alejandro - I hadn't considered the contraction to .=number() - that's useful to know.  Sadly I'm stuck with XPath 1.0 in most of my work at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

**Yet another solution :)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Number[not(.*.+1)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
    <Number>111111</Number>
    <Number>123123+</Number>
    <Number>222222</Number>
    <Number>222222+</Number>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t>
  <Number>111111</Number>
  <Number>222222</Number>
</t>
```

**Explanation**: All `Number` elements for wich the expression:

```
not(.*.+1)
```

is `true()` are filtered out by the simple template rule:

```
 <xsl:template match="Number[not(.*.+1)]"/>
```

This is possible only if the string value of the `Number` element cannot be converted to a number. In this case `.*.+1` evaluates to `NaN` and `boolean(NaN)` is `false()` by definition.

If the string value of the `Number` element can be converted to a number $num, then the above expression is equivalent to:

```
not($num*$num+1)
```

and `$num*$num+1 >= 1` for any number `$num`, so, `boolean(.*.+1)` in this case is always `true()`.